# How to select columns in dataframe using variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (data in testdf dataframe included for replication) with 41 columns. I want to rearrange columns therein in a specific manner. This is because there can be variable number of columns in the original dataset due to the variable number of lags of variables used in the time series regression. The original dataset is then manipulated to include as many columns as required to make the total number of lags of the variables to be the same (7 in this case). Hence, in this dataset, there are 6 usage lags variables and 1 has been added (appears at the end).

The dataframe is shown below :-

```
region,regionalentity,entity,entitycode,dateperiod,dateperiodmax,avgtemp,avgtempcategory,adjavgtemp,adjavgtemptype,dayname,daynum,usage.lag0,intercept,usage.lag-1,usage.lag-2,usage.lag-3,usage.lag-4,usage.lag-5,usage.lag-6,temp.lag0,ciresL1,modelcomputedfittedvalues,usagelevel_L0,usagelevel_L1,fittedlevelusage,fittedlevelusagevar0,fittedlevelusagevarpct,fittedlevelusageabsvar0,fittedlevelusagevarabspct,adjfittedlevelusage,adjfittedlevelusagevar0,adjfittedlevelusagevarpct,adjfittedlevelusageabsvar0,adjfittedlevelusagevarabspct,adjfac,minvarpct,maxvarpct,adjminvarpct,adjmaxvarpct,usage_lag_7
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-08,2019-08-26,12.8,Actual,12.8,Plus_0,Wed,3,-1978.630477847,1,5217.164445177,38381.403272784,-26573.993165182,-3571.086713581,-48.301188955,-865.165969976,1.75,37767.5832575731,-10546.6865414192,154724.804766449,156703.435244296,146156.748702877,8568.05606357215,5.5376098722537,8568.05606357215,5.5376098722537,146156.748702877,8568.05606357215,5.5376098722537,8568.05606357215,5.5376098722537,1,5,10,5,10,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-09,2019-08-26,10.5,Actual,10.5,Plus_0,Thu,4,6219.068623674,1,-1978.630477847,5217.164445177,38381.403272784,-26573.993165182,-3571.086713581,-48.301188955,-2.3,49140.1804479394,-4574.58388500458,160943.873390123,154724.804766449,150150.220881444,10793.6525086786,6.70646995211497,10793.6525086786,6.70646995211497,150150.220881444,10793.6525086786,6.70646995211497,10793.6525086786,6.70646995211497,1,5,10,5,10,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-10,2019-08-26,14.7,Actual,14.7,Plus_0,Fri,5,-47279.361890857,1,6219.068623674,-1978.630477847,5217.164445177,38381.403272784,-26573.993165182,-3571.086713581,4.2,37811.9212791045,-15456.0153096346,113664.511499266,160943.873390123,145487.858080488,-31823.3465812224,-27.9976099500748,31823.3465812224,27.9976099500748,145487.858080488,-31823.3465812224,-27.9976099500748,31823.3465812224,27.9976099500748,1,25,30,25,30,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-11,2019-08-26,11.4,Actual,11.4,Plus_0,Sat,6,34609.477278232,1,-47279.361890857,6219.068623674,-1978.630477847,5217.164445177,38381.403272784,-26573.993165182,-3.3,22575.5057919593,5349.94126323161,148273.988777498,113664.511499266,119014.452762498,29259.5360150004,19.7334247606353,29259.5360150004,19.7334247606353,119014.452762498,29259.5360150004,19.7334247606353,29259.5360150004,19.7334247606353,1,15,20,15,20,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-12,2019-08-26,10.1,Actual,10.1,Plus_0,Sun,7,181.193161194,1,34609.477278232,-47279.361890857,6219.068623674,-1978.630477847,5217.164445177,38381.403272784,-1.3,32008.3823244177,601.787165323653,148455.181938692,148273.988777498,148875.775942822,-420.594004129642,-0.283313791163811,420.594004129642,0.283313791163811,148875.775942822,-420.594004129642,-0.283313791163811,420.594004129642,0.283313791163811,1,0,5,0,5,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-13,2019-08-26,11.4,Actual,11.4,Plus_0,Mon,1,-11354.297567614,1,181.193161194,34609.477278232,-47279.361890857,6219.068623674,-1978.630477847,5217.164445177,1.3,22271.5206463676,-4603.22595618364,137100.884371078,148455.181938692,143851.955982508,-6751.07161143035,-4.92416343074627,6751.07161143035,4.92416343074627,143851.955982508,-6751.07161143035,-4.92416343074627,6751.07161143035,4.92416343074627,1,0,5,0,5,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-14,2019-08-26,13.05,Actual,13.05,Plus_0,Tue,2,-17233.144436292,1,-11354.297567614,181.193161194,34609.477278232,-47279.361890857,6219.068623674,-1978.630477847,1.65,20835.2779179977,-6148.02463599273,119867.739934786,137100.884371078,130952.859735085,-11085.1198002992,-9.24779244718395,11085.1198002992,9.24779244718395,130952.859735085,-11085.1198002992,-9.24779244718395,11085.1198002992,9.24779244718395,1,5,10,5,10,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-15,2019-08-26,14.95,Actual,14.95,Plus_0,Wed,3,12026.579924003,1,-17233.144436292,-11354.297567614,181.193161194,34609.477278232,-47279.361890857,6219.068623674,1.9,16190.4338545925,-1828.25322565582,131894.319858789,119867.739934786,118039.48670913,13854.8331496588,10.5044956935919,13854.8331496588,10.5044956935919,118039.48670913,13854.8331496588,10.5044956935919,13854.8331496588,10.5044956935919,1,10,15,10,15,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-16,2019-08-26,11.7,Actual,11.7,Plus_0,Thu,4,12449.922399102,1,12026.579924003,-17233.144436292,-11354.297567614,181.193161194,34609.477278232,-47279.361890857,-3.25,42712.6323897985,4460.21257151099,144344.242257891,131894.319858789,136354.5324303,7989.709827591,5.53517736669833,7989.709827591,5.53517736669833,136354.5324303,7989.709827591,5.53517736669833,7989.709827591,5.53517736669833,1,5,10,5,10,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-17,2019-08-26,11.8,Actual,11.8,Plus_0,Fri,5,-9762.010530065,1,12449.922399102,12026.579924003,-17233.144436292,-11354.297567614,181.193161194,34609.477278232,0.1,30367.4176907901,-4864.57340900852,134582.231727826,144344.242257891,139479.668848882,-4897.43712105646,-3.63899235298821,4897.43712105646,3.63899235298821,139479.668848882,-4897.43712105646,-3.63899235298821,4897.43712105646,3.63899235298821,1,0,5,0,5,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-18,2019-08-26,11.35,Actual,11.35,Plus_0,Sat,6,22305.952959846,1,-9762.010530065,12449.922399102,12026.579924003,-17233.144436292,-11354.297567614,181.193161194,-0.45,21368.3344560516,-1971.88265162283,156888.184687672,134582.231727826,132610.349076203,24277.8356114689,15.4746105704521,24277.8356114689,15.4746105704521,132610.349076203,24277.8356114689,15.4746105704521,24277.8356114689,15.4746105704521,1,15,20,15,20,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-19,2019-08-26,9.3,Actual,9.3,Plus_0,Sun,7,27244.1359885,1,22305.952959846,-9762.010530065,12449.922399102,12026.579924003,-17233.144436292,-11354.297567614,-2.05,40241.1145869285,-1906.75491557666,184132.320676172,156888.184687672,154981.429772095,29150.8909040767,15.8314905265021,29150.8909040767,15.8314905265021,154981.429772095,29150.8909040767,15.8314905265021,29150.8909040767,15.8314905265021,1,15,20,15,20,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-20,2019-08-26,8.95,Actual,8.95,Plus_0,Mon,1,-6677.68231343,1,27244.1359885,22305.952959846,-9762.010530065,12449.922399102,12026.579924003,-17233.144436292,-0.35,51845.2410212359,-11603.7793657006,177454.638362742,184132.320676172,172528.541310471,4926.0970522706,2.77597536909741,4926.0970522706,2.77597536909741,172528.541310471,4926.0970522706,2.77597536909741,4926.0970522706,2.77597536909741,1,0,5,0,5,9999
VIC,VIC,VIC_TRU,6,2018-08-21,2019-08-26,10.5,Actual,10.5,Plus_0,Tue,2,-14638.358924711,1,-6677.68231343,27244.1359885,22305.952959846,-9762.010530065,12449.922399102,12026.579924003,1.55,42497.3131741632,-16306.3388719971,162816.279438031,177454.638362742,161148.299490745,1667.97994728605,1.02445526518796,1667.97994728605,1.02445526518796,161148.299490745,1667.97994728605,1.02445526518796,1667.97994728605,1.02445526518796,1,0,5,0,5,9999
```

Therefore, the variables are defined as follows :-
maxusagelag <- 6 (this number can change depending upon the number of lags in the time series regression model selected)
maxpossibleusagelags <- 7

```
I want the data frame to be arranged like so :-
1. The first 14 columns as they are
2. The next 6 columns as they are - as 'maxusagelag' = 6 (there are 6 lagged variables of usage in the original data set)
3. Then the last variable (named "usage_lag_7") - 1 column in this case because (maxpossibleusagelags  - maxusagelag = 1)
4. Then all of the remaining columns in the dataset excluding the last as it has already been moved to a different position in step 3 above
```

I tried a whole lot of options that I could think of but nothing worked. Here are some of the things that I tried :-

```
val1 <- ((ncol(testdf) - (maxpossibleusagelags - maxusagelag) + 1):ncol(testdf))
val1 : 41
val2 <- ((15 + maxpossibleusagelags - 1):(ncol(testdf) - (maxpossibleusagelags - maxusagelag)))
val2 : 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
val3 <- ((ncol(testdf) - (maxpossibleusagelags - maxusagelag)))
val3 : 40

paste0(val2, ":", val3)
[1] "21:40"
testdf1 <- testdf[, paste0("c(", val2, ":", val3, ")")]

testdf1 <- dplyr::select(testdf, paste0("c(", val2, ":", val3, ")")])
Error: unexpected ']' in "testdf1 <- dplyr::select(testdf, paste0("c(", val2, ":", val3, ")")]"
```

Is there something that I can do to select the various columns in a dataframe by position using variable names?

Comment: Forming an R command programmatically (`paste0("c(",...,")")`) is really not a good way to go about this: the only way you could get that to work is if you subsequently used `eval`, which invites all sorts of problems (and troubleshooting headaches). Is there a reason you cannot just do `testdf[,val2:val3]`?

Comment: Thanks r2evans <- I can do that but how do I do multiple entries like testdf[, val2:val3, val4:val5] etc. This doesn't seem to work : testdf[, c(val2:val3, val4:val5)]

Comment: Why does that not seem to work? If all of the `val*` variables are integers, that should work just fine. (Cf `mtcars[,c(1:3, 5:6, 4)]`). (Are you certain that they are all non-`NA` numbers?)

Comment: I cannot access my pc now but will show the results of using just that when I do. From what I saw, it outputted a vector like 1 2 3 4 5 6, not the data frame with the relevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

We could try using `grep` to create a regex to select columns dynamically and use `setdiff` to select remaining columns at the end.

```
first_set <- 1:14
second_set <- grep(paste0("lag\\.[1-",maxusagelag, "]"), names(testdf))
combine_set <- c(first_set, second_set, ncol(testdf))
```

and now use it to subset columns

```
testdf[,c(combine_set, setdiff(seq_along(testdf), combine_set))]
```

Comment: Ronak <- Can you please walk me through your solution? I don't understand it. What does 'lag\\•{' do in the grep function?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Can you confirm if it does what you want because I was not sure if this is exactly what you need.

Comment: r2evans <- Here is the output from the following. val2 gives 25, val3 gives 22, Val1 gives 20, testdf1 <- testdf[, c(1:val1, val3:val2)] gives the result as shown below :-
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal We are trying to create a regex which will give index of column numbers where it matches the pattern `paste0("lag\\.[1-",maxusagelag, "]")` i.e `lag\\.[1-6]` here. which means `lag.1`, `lag.2` till `lag.6`.